# http to https htaccess always redirecting to home page

Tags: .htaccess, ssl

I have found following .htaccess code on stackoverflow.com to convert the http requests to https

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

it is converting the http to https but always goes to the home page

suppose If I am trying to go to http://domain.com/about-us it routes me to https://domain.com

Just for information I am using redirect and global redirect module but even if I am disabling them both the result is same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Drupal includes an .htaccess file that has instructions in the comments for doing https redirection.  I suggest you follow the instructions in that file.

From Drupal 7.22:

```
# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  # Set "protossl" to "s" if we were accessed via https://.  This is used later
  # if you enable "www." stripping or enforcement, in order to ensure that
  # you don't bounce between http and https.
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl]
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl:s]
```

Comment: what does this mean Set "protossl" to "s" if we were accessed via https://.  This is used later

Comment: @Fahad You need to read the whole comment... _"This is used later if you enable "www." stripping or enforcement, in order to ensure that you don't bounce between http and https."_

Comment: I dont think this actually does a rewrite ? this just sets a variable to remember we are https

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere halfway the htaccess file drupal rewrites every request to non-existing files to index.php for fancy urls. Be sure to put your rewrite before that.